# Why we use connection string in web.config file.?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-config

In my application, am using connection string in web.config file. As am a starter in .net I have a doubt about this, what are the benefits or why we use connection string in web.config file. Any assistance would be much appreciated..

Answer (score 0):

It is a configuration file where you store all your application settings. With the help of it, connection string becomes configurable i.e without changing build you can change the database to be connected.

Comment: Thank you for the response. :) @Ipsit Gaur

Answer (score 0):

Your question is too vague.

This is my check list when troubleshooting connection string.

1. Ensure proper database driver included in project.
2. Confirm connection and db access permission using other methods. (e.g. use database client tool)
3. Connection string value is legal to the respective database format.

Comment: I think you couldn't understand my question in proper way. Instead of config file we can create a class file and make the connection to db. Other than that am asking what are the benefits with config file.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Because it is much easier to change connection string property when you are using application in production.

Comment: Thank you for the response. :)